# Excel - sum a range calculating wtih functions on the fly

Tags: excel, sum

I want to sum a range of values but if a value on the same row in another column meets a particular condition, I want to perform a function on the value I'm summing. For example, let's say I'm summing a column of dollar amounts, but if a particular amount has, say,  a 'w' in a neighboring column on the same row, I want to sum **twice** the amount, not the dollar amount shown. For instance, say a value in my range is $15.90 and there is a 'w' in the cell two columns over. In that case I would want to add not $15.90 to my sum but 2x$15.90=$31.80

I basically am looking to display one number but sum another. And I don't want to use a hidden column.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

If you have dollar amounts in `A2:A100` and the "w" indicators in `B2:B100` try using `SUMPRODUCT` like this

`=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A100,1+(B2:B100="w"))`

If there are no "w"s you will get the sum only, otherwise the "w" rows will be added twice